# D3.js fixed position group in chord diagram

Tags: d3.js

I am looking for a way to have a fixed position and width of a group in a d3.js chord diagram. Is there a way to do this?

**This is how it is shown by default when drawing the chord diagram:**

[image: Default]

**This is how I would like the top (1st group) to show (wider than the other groups and centered at the top):**

[image: How I want it (group at top, centered)]

Answer (score 1):

If you a fixed data set then you know how much to rotate so that you get your desired position.

I applied rotation on this example: 
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006

So that it become very much of your proposed chart fiddle below:
http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/L9s2dpxt/

To achieve this you will need to give rotation to the main g group like this:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")rotate(100)");
```

//Rotating this by 100 degrees but this can be your choice depending on your dataset.

Next is the rotation of the text this is governed by this code

```
ticks.append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "translate(16)" : null; })//I am just giving translate no rotation
    .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.label; });
```

Comment: Thanks Cyril. That helps a lot. My other issue is that because my chord diagram is dynamic, the groups are always shrinking/expanding when data is added/removed. But that is a separate question I will ask.